# ORDER BY ... IN(...) ASC

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get all profiles first that are for certain location(s):

```
SELECT * FROM profile
WHERE location IN ('a', 'b', 'c') OR isDefault=1 
ORDER BY location IN ('a', 'b') DESC, -- put to the front if location in 'a','b'
         isDefault DESC,              -- for each of both groups, put default profiles before the others.
         location ASC                 -- and sort each of the up to four groups by location.
```

This throws the error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'.". If I remove the order clause, results are returned.

What is wrong here?

Comment: A possible issue with your request is that, apart from the fact that `IN` is not allowed in `ORDER BY`, is that there will be no inner sort of the locations you choose to put "in front". Is that really what you desire? _a_ and _b_ would end up in top, but it might be as _b_ and _a_.

Comment: @Mackan `location ASC` will sort them, so a is always in front of b (if isDefault is same for both), *even* if I query `ORDER BY location IN('b', 'a')`, and this is completely intended.

Comment: True, don't know what I was thinking - but it made perfect sense as I was thinking it ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could rewrite that to give an integer back which is sortable:

```
case when location IN ('a', 'b') then 0 else 1 end DESC
```

Comment: Nice, but if OP wants `a, b` first, then will need to [reverse the flag mapping or the `DESC`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/31ff8/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `IN` in the `ORDER BY`. Change it to:

```
ORDER BY location ASC, --will sort a, then b, then c
```

Comment: And how will that sort `@`? Since the ASCII value of `@` is lower than `a` it will come first, not `a`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman considering `WHERE location IN ('a', 'b', 'c')`, how would @ show up?

Comment: The location `@` for example with come before the `a` now.

Comment: The `@` is not the issue here. It's just an example. The OP apparently wants to prioritize certain locations in the sort, and this will not work then. But I think the question is a bit unclear about this, and using _a, b, c_ makes it worse, so +1 for solution :)

Answer (score 1):

So the ORDER BY Syntax is:

```
ORDER BY column_name ASC|DESC, column_name ASC|DESC
```

So

location IN ('a', 'b')

isDefault

location

have to be Column Names

Try:

```
location DESC
isDefault DESC
```

Also IN can only be used in a WHERE Clause

Sources:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or higher then you can use the [`IIF()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/hh213574(v=sql.110).aspx) command to convert a true/false expression into a result using minimal code.

```
ORDER BY IIF(location IN ('a','b'), 1, 0) ASC
```